# Button does not work in MapView Callout React Native

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

I have implemented 2 buttons in the MapView but when i press on them nothing happens. This is the code below for the 2 buttons:

```
<MapView.Marker
    coordinate={{
    latitude: parseFloat(val.latitude),
    longitude:parseFloat(val.longitude)
    }}
    pinColor={"#8f9491"}
    key={index}


    >
    <MapView.Callout tooltip style={styles.customView}>

        <View style={styles.ParkingPopUpStyle}>

            <Text style = {styles.parkingPopUpText}>
            Postcode : {val.postcode}{"\n"}{"\n"}
            Restrictions: {val.restriction_type}{"\n"}{"\n"}
            Maximum Stay: {val.maximum_stay}{"\n"}{"\n"}
            Tariff : {val.tariff}{"\n"}{"\n"}
            Operating Hours: {val.times_of_operation}{"\n"}{"\n"}
            Nearest Pay Machine: {val.nearest_machine}{"\n"}{"\n"}
            Parking Bay Length: {val.parking_bay_length_metres} {'Metres'}{"\n"}{"\n"}
            Parking Permit Required To Park For Free: {val.controlled_parking_zone}{"\n"}{"\n"}

            </Text>
            <View style={styles.ParkingAvailableButton}>
            <Button title="Mark As Available"
            onPress={()=>this.storeParking()}
            />
            </View>

            <View style={styles.ParkingTakenButton}>
            <Button title="Mark As Taken"
            onPress={()=>this.storeParking()}
            />
            </View>

        </View>
    </MapView.Callout>
</MapView.Marker>
```

Even if I just use a console log instead of a function when the button is pressed, it still does not work. Thanks in advance!

This is the storeParking function:

```
  function storeParking(postcode,lat,long) {
    console.log("----------------------------")
    firebase.database().ref('ParkingSpaces/').push({
     postcode : postcode,
      latitude: lat,
      longitude: long,
  })
  }
```

Comment: where is your ```storeParking``` function?

Comment: inside the same file. I have edited my code

Comment: Your function might be in the same file, but not necessarily in the same scope. So ```this.storeParking``` might not exist if storeParking function is not in the same scope as your component class. Can you post your whole file?